# Remplacer « J'espère que tu vas bien »

Tags: expressions, correspondance

Je commence souvent mes mails ou mes courriers par cette formule

> Bonjour X,
>
> J’espère que tu vas bien ...

Une formule toute faite. Oui, c’est vrai. Mais, est-ce qu'il y a d'autres formules possibles pour ne pas tomber dans la répétition ?

Comment: T'inquiète! Le début d'un courrier... c'est très souvent une formule toute faite. Les périodes de Noël et de jour de l'an qui s'annoncent ne vont pas manquer de te fournir l'occasion de te ... re... nouveler! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il existe un critère de décision à prendre en compte en premier et ce critère c'est la fréquence des envois à une même personne ; si les envois sont quotidiens ou peut être espacés de trois ou quatre jours il y a deux raisons qui font que rechercher la variété dans cette relation de contacts routiniers au moyen de messages, ne soit pas justifiable au vu tout au moins d'une attitude générale que l'on voudrait cohérente ; les contacts de visu quotidiens, ou de pratiquement toute autre fréquence, avec nos semblables ne sont pas commencés par autre chose qu'une ou deux formules standard, « *bonjour* », « *bonjour, comment allez-vous ?*  » ou des variantes comme « *salut* ».

De plus, une formule telle que « *bonjour, comment allez-vous ?* » ne sera pas répétée quotidiennement et restera une formule que l'on utilise après des périodes relativement longues de ne s'être pas rencontrés. Donc, pourquoi rechercher la variété dans le contact par messagerie alors qu'il est impensable de le rechercher dans le contact de visu ?

La seconde raison est une question de variété elle-même ; on ne voudrait pas répéter quelque chose comme « *j'espère que tu vas bien* » parce que l'on ne ressent pas vraiment un souci ou même une curiosité réelle pour le bien-être du correspondant étant donné le temps très court après le dernier contact et on voudrait éviter une routine qui a des chances de passer sinon pour hypocrite, du moins pour celle d'un esprit peu judicieux; il me semble que l'on n'aura pas tort d'essayer d'éviter ce type de routine.

Il resterait alors la solution de varier les formules en utilisant ce qui passe par la tête au moment de la rédaction et qui devra avoir le caractère d'être quelque chose de ressenti, en d'autre mots quelque chose auquel on croit et cela serait peut être idéal. Il n'existe pas un ensemble important de formules ; il n'y a que la possibilité de créer soi-même des formules mais cela comporte une difficulté ; il est difficile pour un correspondant de disposer d'une telle variété sans une relation intense dans laquelle il a  à l'esprit un grand nombre des détails de la vie de son correspondant et de son évolution; on trouve cette sorte de créativité surtout dans la correspondance des intellectuels entre eux et en tant que conclusion de leurs missives. Ce ne sont pas à proprement parler des formules mais des constatations, des expressions d'espoir ou de désespoir, des félicitations, etc. qui impliquent la vie intime, professionnelle et 
sociale des correspondants.

Si l'on se sent de nature à partager un tel idéal on peut alors revenir sur des formules courantes de temps en temps, en particulier lorsque avec une grande fréquence d'envoi, réapparait l'inéluctable situation de n'avoir rien de particulier en quoi l'on puisse « croire ». Le problème est que cela n'est pas possible pour des correspondances aussi fréquentes et avec des individus qui ne sont pas des connaissances intimes ; de surcroit peu de nos connaissances pourront être de cette sorte.

Il semble donc que la seule possibilité soit de s'en tenir à une formule simple comme « *bonjour,* » ou une formule qui consiste seulement du nom de la personne. Il y a peut être des questions quant à la pratique d'utiliser une fois une formule telle que « *Bonjour Jacques,* » puis ensuite seulement « *Jacques,* » et encore une fois « *Bonjour, J'espère que tu vas bien…* » mais personnellement je n'en vois pas de vraiment importante.

Quelques possibilités, pas des plus originales mais l'originalité est une question de cas individuels :

> « Bonjour X, J’espère que tu vas bien ...»
>   « Bonjour X, Encore moi, famas22 qui vais t'embêter un moment, ...»
>   « Bonjour X, En espérant que ta journée soit des meilleures,...»
>   « Bonjour X, Je te souhaite un bon retour de vacances, ...»
>   « Bonjour X, Souhaitons que la reprise du travail ne t'ait pas été désagréable après ces belles vacances,...»

Les fréquences de correspondance de plusieurs semaines permettent plus de liberté ; cependant, tôt ou tard on doit se rabattre sur une répétition, mais alors vu la période de temps assez longue passée sans l'utiliser elle n'est plus de cette sorte gênante qui semble être vide de contenu.

Comment: Je te conseille de formatter ton texte pour le rendre plus lisible. Gras, citations (*>*), sauts de lignes, ... Le pavé du début donne pas vraiment envie de lire. J'ai ajouté des trucs vite fait mais ça reste pas super digeste.

Comment: Merci beaucoup LPH c'est super parfait

Comment: j'espère que tu portes bien est ^possible aussi ?

Comment: @famas22 Oui, bien sûr, mais comme expression quasi synonyme de « aller bien » :[ (TLFi) Aller (bien, mal, médiocrement, etc.). Se porter bien, mal, etc.] Donc, **vous ne changez pas l'idée**; il me semble ne pas me tromper mais votre problème de répétition concernait l'idée. D'autres formes pour la même idée sont les suivantes : « J'espère que tu es en bonne santé », « J'espère que tu gardes/conserves la santé ».

Answer (score 4):

C'est marrant ça le manque d'inspiration...

Bon allez... des bons tuyaux... tu peux en trouver chez les bons auteurs qui n'ont jamais été avares en correspondance... Je m'amuse déjà!

*"Chère Madame et grande amie,
Je voulais spécialement vous remercier de la si affectueuse attention que vous avez eue de m’envoyer du beurre, des sardines et du café vert"*

Ça peut le faire ça non ? Tu balances le contexte et ça classe un poil plus que *j'espère que tu vas bien* non ? Bon... evidemment... faut l'occase aussi... c'est pas tous les jours que tu reçois des sardines je m'imagines...

*"Je vous prie de conserver cette lettre pour vous seul car je vous l'écris uniquement pour vous mettre au courant de choses que vous n'avez pas deviné jusqu'à présent..."*

Hé... pour du passe-partout, c'est pas mal celle-là. Classe DCRI... Pourquoi tu t'fendrais d'un courier sinon ?

Forcément... moi, j'aime bien commencer par :

*"Finalement, j’aimerais bien mieux être professeur à Bâle que Dieu ; mais je n’ai pas osé pousser si loin mon égoïsme privé que, pour lui, je renonce à la création du monde. Voyez-vous..."*

Commencer par *finalement*... c'est-y pas osé ? Oui! C'est vraiment ma préférée mais elle a comme un défaut... en général... je ne reçois pas de réponse... mais bon quand je commence comac... j'en n'attends pas non plus hein... ;-)

Bon... allez! Mais c'est du copié/collé toussa... et donc, fonction du contexte, du fait que tu attends une réponse... ou pas... , fonction de ta relation **sincère** avec qui tu t'adresses, je ne fais pas de doute que... si tu y tiens vraiment... tu puisses faire plus original encore!

Bon! C'est pas l'tout ça mais faut qu'j'écrive à mon @¹@@## de @à!!&?? des impôts... et là... j'suis sec! Tu crois que *j'espère que tu vas bien* pourrait le faire ? Bon... après tout... c'est pas plus bête qu'autre chose... je peux bien essayer... ;-)

---

<sub>NDaCOSwt: le lecteur avisé aura évidemment reconnu dans l'ordre : Antonin Artaud, Camille Claudel et... Friedrich Nietzsche.</sub>

Comment: <offtopic> Pourquoi colles-tu toujours tes points d'exclamation, dont tu n'es d'ailleurs pas avare, alors que tu suis bien les conventions de typographie française pour les points d'interrogation ? </offtopic>

Comment: @jlliagre : **Bien vu!** C'est effectivement systématique... chez moi! ici! Et j'apprécie à sa juste valeur ton intervention sous forme de questionnement. Pourrait-ce pousser à prolonger ce questionnement quant aux multiples autres points sur lesquels j'enfreins manifestement les conventions tout en affichant par ailleurs (discrètement) que je les connais ?

Comment: @jlliagre : Prolonger sur des points autres que de typographie, je veux dire. De syntaxe, de grammaire... etc. Bref! de tout ce qui fait la... sémiotique quoi!

Comment: +1 pour les citations rigolotes (et culturelles) !

Comment: On devrait lui ouvrir une chronique dans le FSE avec le vote « chronique » ; ça épargnerait ses talents et apporterait la libération de l'espace des réponses et commentaires, qu'il a envahit et qui devrait rester quelque chose de fondamentalement pragmatique et didactique…

Comment: @LPH : Ha oui! Mais l'envahissement préalable des commentaires c'est fait pour repousser les vôtres le plus bas possible. Leur concentration en fautes d'orthographe et de grammaire les rendant, vous en conviendrez : disgracieux. Quant à l'épargne de mes talents, ne vous en souciez pas, elle n'est plus d'actualité. Je suis passé à l'Euro il y a un certain temps de cela.

Comment: Vos querelles sont agacantes et selon-moi par leur egocentrisme assez contraires à l'esprit de SE...

Comment: j'espère que tu portes bien est ^possible aussi ?