# J'espère que vous allez parfaitement et ses dérivées

Tags: grammaire, expressions, vocabulaire, politesse

Je donne des cours de mathématiques à un étudiant depuis un an et demi maintenant. Lorsque je planifie l'horaire du prochain cours avec la mère de celui-ci, je commence mes messages par :

> Bonjour [prénom],
> J'espère que vous allez parfaitement,
> [...]

Je trouve, qu'au fil des semaines et messages, plus de 40 par an, cette formulation se répète et j'essaye de varier. J'ai écrit :

> J'espère que vous et votre famille vous portez bien,
> J'espère que tout se passe au mieux pour vous,
> En espérant que vous allez toujours excellemment,
> J'espère que vous allez très bien,
> J'espère comme toujours que tout va au mieux pour vous,
> J'espère que tout va amplement pour vous,

Cependant, j'ai le sentiment que mes formulations se répètent très vite et j'aimerais savoir s'il existe d'autres formes de politesse pour souhaiter, formellement, que mon interlocutrice et éventuellement sa famille se porte au mieux.

Comment: Cette  question et les réponses fournies pourraient fournir une inspiration: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32802/17649

Comment: Pourquoi s'encombrer de formules ? "Bonjour, blablabla, merci, JKHA"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - J'espère que vous êtes en (pleine) forme.
> - J'espère que vous êtes en bonne santé.
> - En espérant que tout marche bien pour vous, (régistre un peu moins formel)

Answer (score 3):

Les formules de politesse sont souvent assez figées, il est difficile de sortir des sentiers battus dans ce domaine.

Parmi les expressions présentées, il y en a qui peuvent plus ou moins surprendre le destinataire.

Classique :

> *J'espère que vous et votre famille vous portez bien*
> *J'espère que tout se passe au mieux pour vous*
> *J'espère comme toujours que tout va au mieux pour vous*

Peut-être un peu excessif mais se rencontre :

> *J'espère que vous allez très bien*

Peu idiomatique, il semble manquer un *bien* à la fin :

> *J'espère que vous allez parfaitement*
> *En espérant que vous allez toujours excellemment*

Pas idiomatique du tout :

> *J'espère que tout va amplement pour vous* (??)

Quelques suggestions:

> *J'espère que vous et votre famille allez bien*
> *J'espère que vous allez bien depuis notre dernier échange de mails*
> *J'espère que vous n'êtes pas trop affectée par la période que nous vivons*