# Conveying 'I trust this message finds you well'

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance

Googling alternatives to 'I hope this message/email finds you well.' I came across '[I trust this email finds you well](https://influno.com/hope-this-email-finds-you-well/)'.

> 5 Alternatives to "I Hope This Email Finds You Well" Sure thing, let’s
> mix things up with a different set of alternatives to the ever-popular
> “I hope this email finds you well.”
>
> Alternative 1: "I trust you are well" This phrase exudes an air of
> professionalism and confidence. It leans on the word “trust,” which
> inherently suggests a certain level of rapport or familiarity with the
> recipient.
>
> By starting your email with “I trust you are well,” you are not just
> passively hoping for the recipient’s well-being, but also confidently
> assuming it. This can help establish a tone of respectful confidence
> right from the get-go, making it particularly effective in formal or
> professional contexts

I am wondering if there is a structure in French that conveys above meaning.

Comment: [Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sur FL: Remplacer [« J'espère que tu vas bien »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32802/358).  1 seconde dans un moteur de recherches pour savoir ce qu'on en pense en France, [La phrase avec laquelle il ne faut pas commencer ses mails professionnels](https://www.cosmopolitan.fr/la-phrase-avec-laquelle-on-ne-commence-pas-ses-mails-professionnels,2055520.asp), [Pourquoi il faut éviter de commencer un e-mail par "j'espère que vous allez bien"](https://www.marieclaire.fr/,pourquoi-il-faut-arreter-d-ecrire-j-espere-que-vous-allez-bien-dans-vos-mails-pro,848644.asp) etc.

Comment: @None I hope you are kidding ; I have been a member for six years. What is wrong with my question? Everyday I received messages with j'espère que vous allez bien/vous vous portez bien. I have found today this interesting English turn with trust and I thought that the best place for asking a French equivalent is Fse. Chatgpt gives je compte que...

Comment: What is not clear with my comments? 1. How would you say "I trust in" French? (minimal search I expect) – 2. I understand you are looking for an alternative to *j'espère que vous allez bien/* (although you do not say so clearly) so I link to a similar question so that you can say why this alternative does not satisfy you. It is easy to find articles on the subject online  which you could have come across before you asked the question, how did they help you or not...

Comment: @None I think that it is obviously that I know how trust can be conveyed  in French. I was wondering how it can be conveyed in this context expressing the idea described in the cited text.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore thanks. Just a side note. Chagpt proposed also trustWhen I asked it why implying I have not heard about time another time,  it replied that this an alternative way in order to avoid hope. I will make a question in ESE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase convenue équivalente est « j'espère que cette lettre te/vous trouvera en bonne santé » ([1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-hope-this-letter-finds-you-well.909913/), [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-hope-this-letter-email-finds-you-well.235351/)). Je ne suis pas convaincu que *trust* signifie autre chose que *hope* mais avec un registre plus [formel](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/trust/619980), mais c'est une question pour un autre site.<sup>1</sup>

Quand on change la phrase figée ça devient inusité et donc moins utile et la phrase ne dispose pas d'équivalent avec un autre verbe. Ceci dit, la 2e du pluriel aide un peu à se rapprocher de l'aspect plus formel de *trust*. On peut penser ajouter *oser* à *espérer* pour tenter d'évoquer la confiance dont le billet parlait, mais c'est davantage perçu comme une [précaution oratoire](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/oser) que de l'assurance. Autrement, on peut penser choisir des temps de verbes plus littéraires mais ça devient rigolo et le présent est requis pour que le destinataire comprenne les propos comme si l'expéditeur s'exprimait devant lui, donc c'est un compromis douteux (et je ne suis pas sûr de la concordance requise vu que la phrase devient inusitée et moins naturelle pour moi) :

> J'ose espérer que cette lettre vous trouvera en bonne santé.
> J'osai espérer que cette lettre vous trouva en bonne santé. (!! hahaha le
> passé simple, Josée qui ?)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Par ailleurs que le perroquet à chatgpt [répète](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54144/conveying-i-trust-this-message-finds-you-well#comment115419_54144) des choses qu'il lit est dans l'ordre des choses ; pour rendre son propos moins aléatoire, des versions spécialisées doivent être entraînées sur un matériel pertinent et non sur l'ensemble des propos de quidams.</sub>